# Tortoise SVN appears to freeze Explorer

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, freeze, tortoise-svn

When updating a repository using Tortoise SVN, Explorer on Windows XP tends to choke and freeze in regular intervals. Something like 4 seconds freeze, 1 second fluent work.

I imagine this may be caused by the (too many) svn:externals? Is this a known issue? Do you know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue

> XP contains a known bug that causes
>   the CPU usage to spike to 100 percent
>   when you access the context menu under
>   certain configurations. This bug
>   causes file-copy operations to halt,
>   network connections to slow, and
>   streaming media (e.g., audio, video)
>   to become distorted. 
>   To work around this bug, you need to disable the GUI's transition effects by performing the following steps:
>
> Start the Control Panel Display applet.
>
> Select the Appearance tab.
>
> Click Effects, then clear the "Use the following transition effect for menus
>   and tooltips" check box.
>
> Click OK to
>   close all dialog boxes.

Comment: Does this require a reboot?

Comment: I always say a reboot doesn't hurt

Comment: I'll try and and accept if it solves the issue :) Thanks!

Comment: It turns out this did not help :(

Comment: Is the problem still occuring

Comment: Yes, I did not notice any difference.

Comment: Actually, I solved it by installing Windows 7 -_-
Going to accept this answer anyway.

Comment: This answer is presented as a quote, and refers to "a known issue"; it would be nice to have a reference for the quote or microsoft KB article or something. As far as I can tell this must be a reference to the TortoiseSVN FAQ: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#hundredcpu