# Windows XP - Explorer CPU spike and freeze

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, freeze, cpu-usage

System: Windows XP SP3, Intel i3

Issue: Windows Explorer process spikes my CPU usage to 50% and freezes.  Only resolution is to kill the process in the Task Manager and restart manually.

Occurrences: Occasionally having an Explorer (note: NOT IE, just Explorer) window open for 15+ minutes causes it to crash.  Any time I copy a file, it crashes 20-30 seconds later.  Always crashes when navigating to network drive, but only after copying file, or waiting 15+ minutes, per above.

I have disabled my roaming profile, removed all Windows Explorer context menu extensions (that I know of).

Has anyone else seen anything like this?

Comment: You can get a list of all installed shell-extension in the tool "Sysinternals Autoruns" on the "Explorer" tab.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Error persists.  Ignore answer below.

Just found the answer:

[Tortoise SVN appears to freeze Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/142819/tortoise-svn-appears-to-freeze-explorer)

I'm not using Tortoise, but the issue is identical.

Comment: That was working for a while...  Crashing again, so the search continues!